# How to expose multiple services with tcp using nginx-ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, configmap

Let's say:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: tcp-services
namespace: ingress-nginx-private
data:
3389: “demo/rdp:3389”`
```

will expose a “rdp” service. If we have 10 services which need to be exposed the same way than how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit this configmap with your new port dynamically.

You could also use Traefik V2, they democratized the TCP/UDP Service through a CRD.

But both case, you need to edit a manifest on the kube.

Comment: I try to add to the same port with a different service but as soon as I save that file it will delete my previous rule and only maintain one rule. 

like this 

`data:
3389: “demo/rdp:3389”
3389: "demo/other:3389"`

Comment: You can’t bins the same port to multiple service. You need to change port

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by nginx ingress docs here: [user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)

You need to edit configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  9000: "default/example-0:8080" 
  9001: "default/example-1:8080" 
  9002: "default/example-2:8080"
```

---

And nginx ingress service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
    - name: proxied-tcp-9000  
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
    - name: proxied-tcp-9001  
      port: 9001
      targetPort: 9001
      protocol: TCP
    - name: proxied-tcp-9002  
      port: 9002
      targetPort: 9002
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

And you can add as many ports as you'd like. Just remeber that one port can only be used once.